# Ajax Button enable / disable

Tags: php, ajax

How do I enable and Disable the button with AJAX get error admin.php:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
function validate() {
    // Find the validation image div
    var validationElement = document.getElementById('nameValidation');
    // Get the form values
    var password1 = document.forms["Admin"]["password1"].value;
    var password2 = document.forms["Admin"]["password2"].value;
    // Reset the validation element styles

    validationElement.style.display = 'none';
    validationElement.className = 'validation-image';
    // Check if password2 isn't null or undefined or empty
    $('#savepasswd').prop('disabled', true);
    if (password2) {
        // Show the validation element
        validationElement.style.display = 'inline-block';
        // Choose which class to add to the element
        $('#savepasswd').removeAttr('disabled');
        validationElement.className += 
            (password1 == password2 ? ' validation-success' : ' validation-error');
    }
}
```

PHP code.

```
$msg .= "  <td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"savepasswd\"  id=\"savepasswd\" value=\"Save Access\" class=\"inputadmin\"></td>\n";
```

Comment: You forgot to load JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently don't have jQuery loaded. You don't need it just for this, you can use plain Javascript.

To disable the button:

```
document.getElementById('savepasswd').disabled = true;
```

To enable the button:

```
document.getElementById('savepasswd').disabled = false;
```